# CS50 pset4 filter reflection

Tags: cs50

```
#include "helpers.h"
#include <math.h>
// Convert image to grayscale
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for ( int h=0 ; h<height ; h++) 
    {
        for (int w=0 ; w<width ; w++)
        {
           int i = image[h][w].rgbtBlue + image[h][w].rgbtGreen + image[h][w].rgbtRed ;
           float j = i/3 ;
           int n = round(j) ;

           image[h][w].rgbtBlue = n ;
           image[h][w].rgbtGreen = n ;
           image[h][w].rgbtRed = n ;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Convert image to sepia
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for ( int h=0 ; h<height ; h++) 
    {
        for (int w=0 ; w<width ; w++)
        {
            float sr = .393 * image[h][w].rgbtRed + .769 * image[h][w].rgbtGreen + .189 * image[h][w].rgbtBlue ;
            float sg = .349 * image[h][w].rgbtRed + .686 * image[h][w].rgbtGreen + .168 * image[h][w].rgbtBlue ;
            float sb = .272 * image[h][w].rgbtRed + .534 * image[h][w].rgbtGreen + .131 * image[h][w].rgbtBlue ;

            int SR = round(sr);
            int SG = round(sg);
            int SB = round(sb);

            if ( SR>255)
            {
                SR = 255 ;
            }
            if (SG>255)
            {
                SG = 255 ;
            }
            if (SB>255)
            {
                 SB = 255 ;
            }

            image[h][w].rgbtBlue = SB ;
            image[h][w].rgbtGreen = SG ;
            image[h][w].rgbtRed = SR ;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Reflect image horizontally
void swap (int *a , int *b) ;

void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int h=0 ; h<height ; h++) 
    {
        for (int w=0 ; w<width/2 ; w++)
        {
            for (int p=width-1 ; p>=round(width/2) ; p--)
            {
                int blue = image[h][w].rgbtBlue ;
                int B = image[h][p].rgbtBlue ;
                swap(&blue , &B);

                int g = image[h][w].rgbtGreen ;
                int G = image[h][p].rgbtGreen ;
                swap(&g , &G);

                int r = image[h][w].rgbtRed ;
                int R = image[h][p].rgbtRed ;
                swap(&r , &R );

            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
void swap (int *a , int *b)
    {
        int tmp = *a ;
            *a = *b ;
            *b = tmp ;
    }

// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    return;
}
```

I have written this code for `helper.c`. It compiles ok and works for grayscale and sepia but fails to reflect the image.

I am stuck in it . Please tell me where have i made the mistake.

Comment: Maybe you can give more information about what's wrong? Does the code compile or not, more about what is the issue,etc. Also, reduce the amount of code, there is no need to paste irrelevant functions which work. Add C tag, not only CS50.

Comment: i took CS50 a while back, they have a separate Stack Exchange community here: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/. You'll have a higher chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Reflect image horizontally
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{

    int tmp[3];
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < width / 2; w++)
        {
            // Place the first pixel in a temporary variable
            tmp[0] = image[h][w].rgbtRed;
            tmp[1] = image[h][w].rgbtGreen;
            tmp[2] = image[h][w].rgbtBlue;
            // Place the opposite pixel one into the first pixel
            image[h][w].rgbtRed = image[h][width - w - 1].rgbtRed;
            image[h][w].rgbtGreen = image[h][width - w - 1].rgbtGreen;
            image[h][w].rgbtBlue = image[h][width - w - 1].rgbtBlue;
            // From the temporary variable extract the first pixel and place it into  
            the opposite pixel
            image[h][width - w - 1].rgbtRed = tmp[0];
            image[h][width - w - 1].rgbtGreen = tmp[1];
            image[h][width - w - 1].rgbtBlue = tmp[2];
        }
    }
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the third for loop

```
for (int p=width-1 ; p>=round(width/2) ; p--)
```

instead, you can assign the opposite pixel inside the second loop as follows:

```
for (int w=0 ; w<width/2 ; w++)
{
    p = width - w - 1;
    ...
}
```